# complex analysis, about the identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Two functions $f$ and $g$ are analytic and never zero in the open unit disc $U$. In addition they satisfy $\frac{f'}{f} ( \frac{1}{n} )=\frac{g'}{g} ( \frac{1}{n} )$. $n=5,6,7,\dots$, find a precise relation between $f$ and $g$ and prove your answer. What I need the most is to find out the identity theorem from this problem.

Comment: "what i need the most is to find out the identity theorem from this problem." I don't understand this. Do you understand the identity principle for analytic functions?

Comment: yes i do. what i mean is that i need to find out the identity theorem by solving this problem

Comment: @joannaghoche: No, you don't: you need to *use* the identity theorem to solve this problem, not to find it out.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ and $g$ are never $0$ in $U$, then $\frac {f'} f$ and $\frac {g'} g$ are analytic on $U$. Since $\frac {f'} f \left( \frac 1 n \right)  = \frac {g'} g \left( \frac 1 n \right)$ for $n \ge 5$, and since $0$ is an accumulation point of $U$, taking the limit gives $\frac {f'} f (0) = \frac {g'} g (0)$, so $\frac {f'} f = \frac {g'} g$ on $U$ by the identity theorem. Rearranging this gives $f'g - fg' = 0$ and, since $g$ is not $0$ on $U$ we may divide by it, in order to obtain $\frac {f'g - fg'} {g^2} = 0$. But this is exactly $\left( \frac f g \right)' = 0$, so $\frac f g$ is a non-zero constant on $U$.